# Use wget to download file above specific size

Tags: wget

I'm using wget to download images from a friend website. However I would like to download only files which size is above 1MB.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why is wget relative? What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: What do you mean by 'relative' ? I use wget to download all files within a web directory. I haven't found anything that can help filtering with size so right now I can only download all files within that directory.

Comment: Searching for "size" in [*GNU Wget 1.18 Manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) yields no promising results. I think [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/html/filters.html) can do this. Do you really have to stick to `wget`? Or is `wget` just a part of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)?

Comment: If you are using linux, you can write a bash script to do this. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32405877/3091398)

Comment: Interesting script. I've tried it but whatever size I put I get files under it. For example I set > 1000000 so as to get file above 1MB but still small files of 100 bytes get downloaded.

Comment: Wget is a part if XY problem. I looked up on how to download all files within a directory and looks like wget was the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can acheive this with assembly, c, python, bash, (grease|tamper)monkey

Your generic approach would be;

1. http-get the directory index
2. parse the file size for each record
3. filter out files larger than one megabyte
4. http-get each file

---

I meant *relevant* in the comment.